# How can I convert Blender file for use by CAD/CAM?

Tags: objects

I found on YouTube tutorial about drawing cycloid rotor. It is piece of cake for the Blender but very difficult to do on CAD. Can I do it on Blender and transfer to CAD. I tried STL. but no luck.

Comment: What file types have you tried exporting it as? CAD programs often work with many of the files that blender can export.

Comment: "I tried STL. but no luck" What happened, what exactly have you tried and what didn't work?

Comment: Also, what CAD program are you trying to use?  Blender is a polygon modeler, flat faces; no reliable precision for curved surfaces. (I'm betting you did not use NURBS.) You can subdivide and do more, and that might be enough for what you're trying to do...   But if you need it in CAD, you'll probably need to learn how to model it in CAD anyway. You can usually bring in a STL/OBJ or something file as reference.  ...we need more detail to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Many CAD/CAM packages prefer "solid" objects, not the lighter weight mesh files usually exported from Blender. STL is common in additive manufacturing - hence there are many work flows that will convert STL to either STEP/STP or IGES.  OBJ files are also common for conversion,  and many packages allow their import.  Check the Import types for your Application, then export/convert accordingly.
I have many times used STL to STEP converters - then cleaned up in CAD.
Hope this helps. Good luck.